# Как отключить клик при касании touchpad в ubuntu?

Tags: x11, ubuntu

Поставил `gsynaptics`.В главном меню unity его нет.В /usr/bin/ также нет.

Где тогда его искать?Ставил через `apt-get install` - установилось, нигде нет.Ставил через центр приложений убунту - также после установки нигде нет.

Уже стал пытаться отключить в консоли.Хочу отключить клик при касании. В `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` вписал следущее:

> Section "InputDevice"

```
    Identifier "Synaptics Touchpad"    Driver "synaptics"    Option "SendCoreEvents" "true"    Option "Device" "/dev/psaux"    Option "Protocol" "auto-dev"    Option "SHMConfig" "true"    Option "HorizEdgeScroll" "0"    Option "MinSpeed" "0.7"    Option "MaxSpeed" "1.2"    Option "AccelFactor" "0"    Option "FastTaps" "False"    Option "TouchpadOff" "2"EndSection
```

Не помогло.

Отключить пытаюсь на `wacom bamboo touch`.Может там другой драйвер?

Как быть? Помогите.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте драйвер на wacom. Думаю, после этого, проблема сама решится.

- [Wacom на  help.ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom)
- [HOW TO Set Up the Bamboo Pen & Touch in Lucid](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9496609&postcount=1)

Comment: Дрова установил и все работает (планшетик и тачпэд), но отключить клик при касании там негде, увы.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить Option "Button1" "0" в xorg.conf.

Answer (score 0):

gnome-mouse-properties в консоли, или, что то типа система -> параметры -> мышь

Comment: Там не возможно отключить клик

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался - через утилиту xsetwacom.